# How to overcome this Problem in tendermint installation?

Tags: tendermint

I followed the installation of tendermint according to instructions from the tendermint home page. While installing, I have the following problem. Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

`lilly@lilly-VirtualBox:~/tendermint$ make tools
Get Certstrap package github.com/square/certstrap@v1.2.0: invalid github.com/ import path
"github.com/square/certstrap@v1.2.0"
tools.mk:70: recipe for target '/home/lilly/go/bin/certstrap' failed
make: *** [/home/lilly/go/bin/certstrap] Error 1`

Answer (score 1):

What version of Go are you using? if it's 1.14+ you will have to add `export GO111MODULE=on` because it may be in `GOPATH` mode.

Comment: Hi marbar3778, The go version I'm using is 1.14 and I added the GO111MODULE as you asked me in my linux machine. And now, I'm getting the following error,

Comment: I'm using go 1.14 @marbar3778 . After setting GO111MODULE  I'm getting    `lilly@lilly-VirtualBox:~/tendermint$ make tools
go: unknown environment setting GO111MODULE=ON
go: unknown environment setting GO111MODULE=ON
go: unknown environment setting GO111MODULE=ON
go: unknown environment setting GO111MODULE=ON
go: unknown environment setting GO111MODULE=ON
go: unknown environment setting GO111MODULE=ON
Get Certstrap
go: unknown environment setting GO111MODULE=ON
tools.mk:70: recipe for target '/bin/certstrap' failed
make: *** [/bin/certstrap] Error 1`

Comment: Hi @marbar3778, I set the GO111MODULE. I figured out the previous error. But now I'm getting this new error. `lilly@lilly-VirtualBox:~/tendermint$ make tools go: writing go.mod cache: mkdir /home/lilly/go/pkg/mod: permission denied
go: writing stat cache: mkdir /home/lilly/go/pkg/mod: permission denied
go: downloading github.com/square/certstrap v1.2.0
go get github.com/square/certstrap@v1.2.0: mkdir /home/lilly/go/pkg/mod: permission denied
tools.mk:70: recipe for target '/home/lilly/go/bin/certstrap' failed
make: *** [/home/lilly/go/bin/certstrap] Error 1`